# create \newtcolorbox with multiple options not working

Tags: numbering, counters, tcolorbox

I would like to create an advanced `\newtcolorbox` with multiple options and an auto counter but can't get it to work...

The MWE is:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}



\newtcolorbox {mybox4}[2][]
{
enhanced,
colback=white,
colframe=red!65!black,
enlarge top by=10mm,
overlay={%
\path[fill=blue!65,line width=.4mm] (frame.north west)--++(17mm,0)coordinate(n2)--++(0,8mm)--++(-20mm,0) arc (-90:90:-4mm)--cycle;
\node at ([shift={(5mm,4mm)}]frame.north west){\color{white}{
\textbf{\sffamily #1}}};
\path[fill=red!65!blue] ([xshift=.4mm]n2)--++(0,8mm)--++(7mm,0)--++(0,-8mm)--cycle;
\node at ([shift={(4mm,4mm)}]n2){\color{white}{\textbf{\sffamily \themycounter}}};
\node at ([shift={(18mm,4mm)}]n2){
\itshape\textbf{\sffamily #2}};
}}

\newcounter{mycounter}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%TCOLORBOXES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}


\begin{mybox4}{sample}{Solution}
{step=mycounter,label=\themycounter}
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.\par
a lot of text here ... This is Example \ref{one}
\tcblower
some text
\end{mybox4}



\end{document}
```

Merci in advance A

Comment: You're are totally misusing `\newtcolorbox` etc. here. If want an auto counter, defining another counter isn't necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless using the `\NewTColorBox` macro, the syntax of `\newtcolorbox` is

`\newtcolorbox[init options]{boxname}[number of args][default opt arg]{option}`.

The init options can be `auto counter` or `use counter`, depending on the requests.

The optional argument should be used here in order to change the default settings of the boxed, usually being specified at the end of the options with `#1`.

The `step` option is not really necessary any longer ('citing' from `tcolorbox` manual, page 98):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{mybox4}[3][]{
  enhanced,
  colback=white,
  colframe=red!65!black,
  enlarge top by=10mm,
  overlay={%
    \path[fill=blue!65,line width=.4mm] (frame.north west)--++(17mm,0)coordinate(n2)--++(0,8mm)--++(-20mm,0) arc (-90:90:-4mm)--cycle;
    \node at ([shift={(5mm,4mm)}]frame.north west){\color{white}{
        \textbf{\sffamily #2}}};
    \path[fill=red!65!blue] ([xshift=.4mm]n2)--++(0,8mm)--++(7mm,0)--++(0,-8mm)--cycle;
    \node at ([shift={(4mm,4mm)}]n2){\color{white}{\textbf{\sffamily \thetcbcounter}}};
    \node at ([shift={(18mm,4mm)}]n2){
      \itshape\textbf{\sffamily #3}};
  },
  #1
}

\newcounter{mycounter}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%TCOLORBOXES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}


\begin{mybox4}[label=one]{sample}{Solution}
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.\par
a lot of text here ... This is Example \ref{one}
\tcblower
some text
\end{mybox4}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: merci @Christian Hupfer.  I understand, the approach is obviously not the right one. Then how can I autonumber the boxes showing just the ongoing number but not using the label? I would then rather use the label to reference within the document like \label{}...How can I achieve that?

Comment: Does your remark "...change the default settings of the boxed, usually being specified at the end of the options with #1..." related to the \newtcolorbox definitions or to any general settings in tcolorbox boxes? And is it mandatory to set this #1 argument always at the end as 'placeholder' for any options or can I put it also at the beginning?

Comment: @aerioeus: you can't without screwing up  the mechanism. You need label=....

Comment: If you place #1 at the beginning you will override the settings by other ones. That's a logical error!

Comment: Merci for the insights @Christian Hupfer !